# Connect to ASP.NET Core SignalR API server to uwp signalR client

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, connection, signalr

When I run my app, I keep getting the following: ConnectionID required

So I can't seem to be able to connect my ASP.NET Core API server to my asp.net uwp client.

I have installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` 1.1.0 nuget package on my server side and the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client` 2.4.1 nuget package on my client side.

This is my `Startup.cs` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FlightAppContext"));
        });

        services.AddSession();

        services.AddOpenApiDocument(c =>
        {
            c.DocumentName = "apidocs";
            c.Title = "FlightApp API";
            c.Version = "v1";
            c.Description = "The FlightApp API documentation description.";
            c.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SecurityDefinitionAppender("JWT Token", new SwaggerSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = SwaggerSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = SwaggerSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
                Description = "Copy 'Bearer' + valid JWT token into field"
            }));
            c.OperationProcessors.Add(new OperationSecurityScopeProcessor("JWT Token"));
        }); //for OpenAPI 3.0 else AddSwaggerDocument();

        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

        services.AddScoped<IEntertainmentRepository, EntertainmentRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IOrderlineRepository, OrderlineRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IPassengerRepository, PassengerRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IPersonnelRepository, PersonnelRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IPassengerGroupRepository, PassengerGroupRepository>();

        services.AddScoped<ApplicationDataInitializer>();
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()));
    }

    //This method gets called by the runtime.Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDataInitializer dataInitializer)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            //The default HSTS value is 30 days.You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();
        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseSignalR(route => route.MapHub<ChatHub>("/api/Chat/GetAllChatMessages"));
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();
        app.UseSwagger();
        dataInitializer.InitializeData();
    }
}
```

This is my `ChatHub.cs` class:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task SendMessage(int PassengergroupId, string userName, string message, DateTime sendTime)
    {
        return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", userName, message, sendTime);
        //Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Convert.ToString(PassengergroupId));
        //return Clients.Groups(Convert.ToString(PassengergroupId)).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", userName, message, sendTime);

    }
}
```

this is my ChatController:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Adds a message to a passengroup
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">message to post</param>
    [HttpPost("ChatMessages")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMessage(MessageDTO message)
    {
        PassengerGroup passengerGroup = _passengerGroupRepository.GetById(message.PassengergroupId);
        Passenger currentUser = _passengerRepository.GetById(message.PassengerId); 
        Message messageToCreate = new Message(currentUser, passengerGroup, message.Content);
        await _dbContext.Messages.AddAsync(messageToCreate);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all messages from passengergroup
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet("GetAllChatMessagesFromPassengerGroup/{id}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MessageDTO>> GetAllChatMessagesFromPassengerGroup(int id)
    {
        var messages = await _dbContext.Messages.Include(m => m.Passenger)
            .Include(m=>m.PassengerGroup).Where(e => e.PassengroupId == id).ToListAsync();
        ICollection<MessageDTO> messagesDTO = new List<MessageDTO>();
        foreach (var m in messages)
        {
            MessageDTO message = new MessageDTO(m);
            messagesDTO.Add(message);
        }
        return messagesDTO;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all messages 
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet("GetAllChatMessages")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MessageDTO>> GetAllChatMessages()
    {

        var messages = await _dbContext.Messages.Include(m => m.Passenger)
            .Include(m => m.PassengerGroup).ToListAsync();
        ICollection<MessageDTO> messagesDTO = new List<MessageDTO>();
        foreach (var m in messages)
        {
            MessageDTO message = new MessageDTO(m);
            messagesDTO.Add(message);
        }
        return messagesDTO;
    }
}
```

and this is my Chat.xaml.cs class:

```
 public sealed partial class Chat : Page
{

    public HubConnection hubConnection;
    public IHubProxy hubProxy;
    public ObservableCollection<Message> MessagesList { get; set; }
    private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public Chat()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public int CurrentPassengerId;
    private Passenger current;

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentPassengerId = e.Parameter.ToString();
        this.CurrentPassengerId = Int32.Parse(currentPassengerId);
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        GetCurrentUser(CurrentPassengerId);
        LoadMessages(current.PassengerGroupId);

        InitilizeHub(current.PassengerGroupId);
    }

    private async void GetCurrentUser(int id)
    {
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri($"http://localhost:53385/api/Passenger/{id}"));
        current = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Passenger>(json);
        this.userTextBlock.Text = current.FirstName + current.LastName;
    }

    private async void InitilizeHub(int id)
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection($"http://localhost:53385/api/Chat/GetAllChatMessages");
        hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
        hubProxy.On<string, string, DateTime>("receiveMessage", GetMessage);

        await hubConnection.Start();

        if (hubConnection.State != ConnectionState.Connected)
        { await hubConnection.Start(); }


    }

    private async void GetMessage(string userName, string message, DateTime sendTime)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            this.MessageListbox.Items.Add($"{sendTime.ToString("HH:mm")}\n{userName}: {message}")
        );
    }

    private async void SendButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await hubProxy?.Invoke("sendMessage", current.PassengerGroupId, userTextBlock.Text, messageTextBox.Text, DateTime.Now);
        var message = new Message(messageTextBox.Text, userTextBlock.Text, current.PassengerGroupId);
        var messageJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        var res = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:53385/api/Chat/ChatMessages",
            new StringContent(messageJson, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        messageTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    public async void LoadMessages(int id)
    {
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri($"http://localhost:53385/api/Chat/GetAllChatMessagesFromPassengerGroup/{id}"));
        var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Message>>(json);
        foreach (var message in lst)
        {
            MessagesList.Add(message);
            this.MessageListbox.Items.Add($"{message.TimeSend.ToString("HH:mm")}\n{message.Name}: {message.Content}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where `ConnectionID required` warning throw, uwp client app or Asp.Net service?

Comment: it is thrown in the asp.net service, and as a result, everything in my hubconnection and hubproxy remains null